# Setting type of ng-animate CSS animation on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Im trying to implement something where clicking on a link or button will implement a given CSS transition depending on which button was clicked.

For example, perhaps I click on a nav link to a login page, I may want to employ a "slide from left" transition. But if I click on a link to a login page from somewhere within the app, I may want to use a "slide from bottom" transition instead.

Right now I have the following code that sets the type of transition based on the class on that element.

**HTML**

```
<div class="slideleft ng-enter"> Slide from left </div>

<div class="slideup ng-enter"> Slide from buttom </div>
```

**CSS**

```
@keyframes slideLeft {
    to      { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

@keyframes slideInUp {
    from    { transform:translateY(100%); }
    to      { transform: translateY(0); }
}

.slideLeft.ng-enter { animation: slideLeft 0.2s both ease-in; z-index: 8888; }

.slideup.ng-enter { animation: slideLeft 0.2s both ease-in; z-index: 8888; }
```

I would like something like the following:

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn1">Transition with slide left</button>

<button class="btn2">Transition with slide up</button>

<div class="slideLeftOrUp ng-enter"> slide left or up depending where btn1 or btn2 clicked </div>
```

How can I implement something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've read this right and you want .btn1/.btn2 to cause .ng-enter to enter, but differently dependent on which is clicked?

You could change a variable on click attached to both those buttons, which the entering element would behave differently based on.

```
<button class="btn1" ng-click="btnClicked='enter-left'"></button>
<button class="btn2" ng-click="btnClicked='enter-top'"></button>

<div class="ng-enter" ng-class="btnClicked"></button>
```

This would add a class to .ng-enter of either .enter-left or .enter-top based on what was clicked, which you could then give corresponding css animations/transitions.